How to get max participated each day id's | Oracle
I am little bit stuck how to write query for certain scenario
Table : employee
create table employee
(
   name varchar2(10),
   sdate date,
   subid number
);

insert into dummy values ('Arun',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),123);
insert into dummy values ('Arun',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),453);
insert into dummy values ('Raj',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),12);
insert into dummy values ('Raj',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),45);
insert into dummy values ('Raj',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),16);
insert into dummy values ('Raj',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),18);
insert into dummy values ('Darshan',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1600);
insert into dummy values ('Darshan',to_date('2016-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),1820);

Below is the data I have in table
name,date,subid
Arun,2016-03-01,123
Arun,2016-03-01,453
Raj,2016-03-01,12
Raj,2016-03-01,45
Raj,2016-03-01,16
Raj,2016-03-01,18
Darshan,2016-03-01,1600
Darshan,2016-03-01,1820

Now I need to filter in such way that maximum time subid participated for name each day
Arun    -> count -> 2  -> 2016-03-01
Raj     -> count -> 4  -> 2016-03-01
Darshan -> count -> 2  -> 2016-03-01

Output :
name , subid , date
Raj  , 12    , 2016-03-01   

For suppose if this occurs like Raj and Darshan as same count then order name wise and pick lesser subid for that name
name,date,subid
Arun,2016-03-01,123
Arun,2016-03-01,453
Raj,2016-03-01,12
Raj,2016-03-01,45
Raj,2016-03-01,16
Raj,2016-03-01,18
Darshan,2016-03-01,1600
Darshan,2016-03-01,1820
Darshan,2016-03-01,160
Darshan,2016-03-01,18

Arun    -> count -> 2  -> 2016-03-01
Raj     -> count -> 4  -> 2016-03-01
Darshan -> count -> 4  -> 2016-03-01

Alpabetical order
Arun    -> count -> 2  -> 2016-03-01
Darshan -> count -> 4  -> 2016-03-01
Raj     -> count -> 4  -> 2016-03-01

Pick lesser subid for Darshan
Output :
name      , subid , date
Darshan   , 18    , 2016-03-01

I cannot able to identify how to achieve it.
I thought of doing partition by on what basis need to partition ?

You appear to want to:

GROUP BY the rows by name and day TRUNC(dt);
Find the MINimum subid in each group;
ORDER the groups in DESCending order of the number of rows in each group (COUNT(*)) and then, if there are ties, in ASCending order of name.
FETCH only the FIRST ROW, which will have the greatest count and earliest name.

Like this:
SELECT name,
       TRUNC(dt) AS dt,
       MIN(subid) AS subid
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name, TRUNC(dt)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, name ASC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE employee( name, sdate, subid) AS
SELECT 'Aarna',  DATE '2016-03-01',  123 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aarna',  DATE '2016-03-01',  453 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brinda', DATE '2016-03-01',   12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brinda', DATE '2016-03-01',   45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brinda', DATE '2016-03-01',   16 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Brinda', DATE '2016-03-01',   18 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chara',  DATE '2016-03-01', 1600 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Chara',  DATE '2016-03-01', 1820 FROM DUAL

Outputs:



NAME
DAY
SUBID




Brinda
2016-03-01 00:00:00
12



If you then insert a couple more rows:
INSERT INTO employee( name, sdate, subid)
SELECT 'Aarna',  DATE '2016-03-01',    1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Aarna',  DATE '2016-03-01',   42 FROM DUAL;

and run the same query again, the output is now:



NAME
DAY
SUBID




Aarna
2016-03-01 00:00:00
1




If you have multiple days then you can use ROW_NUMBER to find the maximum count and then first name for each day:
SELECT name,
       day,
       subid
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
       TRUNC(sdate) AS day,
       MIN(subid) AS subid,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY TRUNC(sdate)
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, name
       ) AS rn
FROM   employee
GROUP BY name, TRUNC(sdate)
)
WHERE  rn = 1;

or:
SELECT name,
       TRUNC(sdate) AS day,
       MIN(subid) AS subid,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
         PARTITION BY TRUNC(sdate)
         ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, name
       ) AS rn
FROM   employee
GROUP BY name, TRUNC(sdate)
ORDER BY rn
FETCH FIRST ROW WITH TIES

However, your data does not have multiple days so the output would be identical.
fiddle

Your answers are awsome but quit confusing not able to understand. could you elaborate more step by step

If its a multiple dates  then its was only for first date  for second date also as some data need to find amost second date then

Thanks @MT0. By taking reference I learned to write query.
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            sdate,
            name,
            MIN(subid)   AS min_subid,
            COUNT(subid) AS max_participated
        FROM
            emp_data
        GROUP BY
            sdate,
            name
        ORDER BY
            COUNT(subid) DESC,
            name
    ) where rownum=1;

